# 1から99までの奇数の合計　パイソン

Tags: python

1から99の奇数の合計をパイソンで教えて下さい。while文を使用して下さい。お願いします。

Comment: スタックオーバーフローではプログラムの作成依頼的な質問は回答が集まりづらい傾向があります。動かなくても構わないのでご自身が試したテストコードや試行錯誤した履歴を載せるととより回答が集まりやすいでしょう

Comment: プログラミングを始めたばかりの方なのかもしれませんが、ご自身で調べて解決にたどり着いた方が勉強になると思います。こちらのサイトで質問できるくらい情報を集めることができるのですから、検索ワードをもうひと工夫すれば、同じような問題を扱っている解説サイトが見つかるかもしれません。回答が得られるのを待っているより早いのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

ネタでよければ（宿題や課題は自分でやろうな。丸投げは嫌われます）

```
while False: pass
else: print (2500);
```

これだけのために５分も調査してしまった (`python` 空文とか)

Comment: 質問内容がはっきりしない状態においてはこれも一つの回答なのかもしれませんが、宿題や課題なのかは本人から明言されていませんし、"～しような" という言い回しは [行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct) と照らし合わせても、礼節を欠いた発言のように思います。

Comment: 宿題だから、という部分を指摘するのは無意味に思います。質問の出自ではなくその内容で判断するべきですし、更にそのことは回答ではなく投票やコメント、クローズ票などで表現すべきでしょう。ご回答の内容を見直していただけませんでしょうか。参考: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/19110